# Use the existing viewresource of asp.net mvc in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am in the middle of porting a web application of ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core MVC. I need help in using the existing view resource as-is in the migrated project. How can I achieve it

In the ASP.NET MVC project, we have a common `viewresource.resx` file and in the views folder we have a `web.config` file where we specify the namespace to be used by all the Razor pages. Something like this

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="mynamesapace.Resources" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Now since in ASP.NET Core MVC in views folder, there is no `web.config` file how do I reuse the razor pages in ASP.NET Core MVC since they use `viewResources`. The namespace `mynamesapace.Resources` is the namespace defined in `viewResource.cs` that is code behind of `ViewResources.resx` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to use the common namespace and the answer is to use `_ViewImports.cshtml` in the views folder. We can use common namespace, Tag Helpers and other.